# A For loop to replace vector value

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, montecarlo

I couldn't figure out what's the problem on my code. Basically i'm trying to do a small version of Monte Carlo simulation.

This is my input

```
mydata=[1,4,20,23,37]
prediction=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
randomvar=runif(12,0,1)
```

and then i have this condition:

> if i-th value of `randomvar` is > 0.97, replace i-th value of `prediction` with 5th data from `mydata`

> else if i-th value of `randomvar` is > 0.93, replace i-th value of `prediction` with 4th data from `mydata`

> else if i-th value of `randomvar` is > 0.89, replace i-th value of `prediction` with 3rd data from `mydata`

> else if i-th value of `randomvar` is > 0.85, replace i-th value of `prediction` with 2nd data from `mydata`

> else if i-th value of `randomvar` is > 0.81, replace i-th value of `prediction` with 1st data from `mydata`

> else 0

and so i wrote this:

```
mydata=c(1,4,20,23,37)
prediction=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
random=runif(12,0,1)
for (i in random) {
  if (i>0.97) prediction[i]=mydata[5]
  else if (i>0.93) prediction[i]=mydata[4]
  else if (i>0.89) prediction[i]=mydata[3]
  else if (i>0.85) prediction[i]=mydata[2]
  else if (i>0.81) prediction[i]=mydata[1]
  else prediction[i]=0
}
prediction
```

The result is

```
> prediction
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I wonder why the code won't change the prediction value based on the condition above. Could anyone help and explain why? I'm new to R anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is not working because, random values generated using `runif` are not integers.

```
> random=runif(12,0,1)
> random
 [1] 0.78381826 0.97424261 0.87240491 0.20896106 0.95598721 0.11609102 0.02430861
 [8] 0.24213124 0.45808710 0.28205870 0.51469212 0.02672362
```

Now `prediction[i]` where `i` is in `random` is meaningless.

do it --

```
for (i in seq_along(random)) {
  if (random[i]>0.97) prediction[i]=mydata[5]
  else if (random[i]>0.93) prediction[i]=mydata[4]
  else if (random[i]>0.89) prediction[i]=mydata[3]
  else if (random[i]>0.85) prediction[i]=mydata[2]
  else if (random[i]>0.81) prediction[i]=mydata[1]
  else prediction[i]=0
}
prediction
> prediction
 [1]  0  0  0  0 20  4  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, now i see that the fundamental problem is from the type of the data. Aside from that, could you explain why are you changing the i into random[i] and cannot simply use i inside the loop?

Comment: Just because `i` is the index number and not the ith value in vector.  To replace the value in vector, we have to use `vector[i]`